# Can't remove applications

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, authentication, se-applications

A couple days ago I added a application from [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/), now for some reason I can't remove it.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Have an application on your account
- Go to your profile (Edit Profile & Settings)
- Site Settings > Applications
- Select one application you have there
- Click "remove"
- Click "Ok" in the alert

**What it should happen:**

- App should be removed

**What actually happens:**

- You get a 404 error on console:
  [image]
  Looks to be a issue on all StackExchange websites. I tried removing the application from stackapps, stackoverflow and meta.

Comment: Confirmed.  Can't remove SE apps like Winterbash, or the API Doc engine, either.

Comment: 2022-03-30: While this issue was fixed, a similar issue existed from *at least* 2021-09-26 to current (as of my posting this comment). You can find the post for that one, with workarounds, at: "[Removing granted access to an Application is no longer working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370293/271271)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report Andre - this should be fixed and deployed network wide.

Comment: Thank you, its working again.